# change html attributes with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, validation

I have a html index document with a called "container" div tag, I load "login.php" into div tag through ajax statement in "indexScript.js". I want load "successfulLogin.php" in the same tag if the "userNameBox" and "passBox" data is in the database table but if call the "validateLogin" method from the "action" attribute of "loginForm" the page is reloaded externally to index document and is displayed without navigation bar and without everything else. Any idea ?

index.html:

```
<head>
    <title>English Site</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/layout.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="indexScript.js"></script>
</head>
<nav><!--Barra de navegacion...!-->
    <ul>
        <li><a id="loginLink">Iniciar sesión</a></li>
        <li><a id="registerLink">Registro</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Estudiantes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Docentes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contenido</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Diccionario</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>  
<div id="container">
    <!--Container content-->
</div>
```

login.php:

```
 <html>
<?php include_once("validateLogin.php"); ?>
    <body>
        <h3>Formulario de ingreso...!</h3>
        <form action="<?php validateLogin(); ?>" onSubmit="return(validateLoginForm());" method="post" id="loginForm" name="loginForm">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><p id="failedLoginLabel" style="color: #B5090B; font-style: italic; font-size: 16px; visibility: hidden;">El nombre de usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos...!</p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" id="userNameBox" name="userNameBox" value="Nombre de usuario" onFocus="this.value=(this.value=='Nombre de usuario')? '' : this.value ;" onBlur="this.value=(this.value=='')? 'Nombre de usuario' : this.value ;" style="width: 70%;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="password" id="passBox" name="passBox" value="Contraseña" onFocus="this.value=(this.value=='Contraseña')? '' : this.value ;" onBlur="this.value=(this.value=='')? 'Contraseña' : this.value ;" style="width: 70%;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Login" style="width: 71%; height: 30px;"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
```

indexScript.js:

```
window.addEventListener("load", load, false);

var registerLink, loginLink, container;

function load(){
    container               = document.getElementById("container");
    registerLink            = document.getElementById("registerLink");
    loginLink               = document.getElementById("loginLink");

    registerLink.addEventListener("click", showRegisterForm, false);
    loginLink.addEventListener("click", showLoginForm, false);
} 
function showLoginForm(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            container.innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
    };
    request.open("POST", "login/login.php", true);
    request.send();
}

function validateLoginForm(){
    var validation              = true;
    var userName                = document.loginForm.userNameBox;
    var pass                        = document.loginForm.passBox;
    var failedLoginLabel        = document.getElementById("failedLoginLabel");
    if(userName.value == "Nombre de usuario" || pass.value == "Contraseña"){
        failedLoginLabel.style.visibility = "visible";
        validation = false;
    }else{
        failedLoginLabel.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    return validation;
}
```

validateLogin.php:

```
<?php
function validateLogin(){
    $userName = $_POST["userNameBox"];
    $password = $_POST["passBox"];
    require_once("../connection/connection.php");
    $connection = Connection::getConnection();
    $query = "select * from english_students_table where user=:userNameMarker";
    $result = $connection->prepare($query);
    $success = $result->execute(array(":userNameMarker" => $userName));
    $register = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($success && password_verify($password, $register["password"])){
        session_start(); /* Crea una sesión o reanuda la actual basada en un identificador de sesión pasado mediante una petición GET o POST, o mediante una cookie.*/
        $_SESSION["userSession"] = $_POST["userNameBox"];
        echo("<script> successfulLogin(); </script>");
    }else{
        echo("<script> failedLogin(); </script>");
    }
}
?>
```

connection.php:

```
<?php
class Connection{
    public static function getConnection(){
        $dbHost = "localhost";
        $dbName = "test_database";
        $dbUser = "root";
        $dbPassword = "";
        $connection = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbName; host=$dbHost", $dbUser, $dbPassword);
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return($connection);
    }
}
?>
```

successfulLogin.htlm:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>Login exitoso...!</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php is client-side and therefore is running as the page is compiling, where as the js is client-side, after page compiles. So this `action="<?php validateLogin(); ?>"` is coming back to either:

```
<form action="<script> successfulLogin(); </script>"
```

or

```
<form action="<script> failedLogin(); </script>"
```

Neither of these I think are what you want and is likely why you are getting the page submit. If you have errors on, you will find that the `$_POST` values will show as undefined in that function. You want to send both via ajax. I will show you using jQuery ajax (only because I know it better, but the principles are the same, which is the important part):

I am just adding the jquery library here:

```
<head>
    <title>English Site</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/layout.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="indexScript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="indexScript.js"></script>
</head>
<nav><!--Barra de navegacion...!-->
    <ul>
        <li><a id="loginLink">Iniciar sesión</a></li>
        <li><a id="registerLink">Registro</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Estudiantes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Docentes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contenido</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Diccionario</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>  
<div id="container">
    <!--Container content-->
</div>
```

Now you need to have an engine to run ajax:

**/js/myscripts.js**

```
// Create a custom re-useable ajax function
var MyAjaxEngine = function($)
{
    var self = this;
    this.ajax = function(data,func)
    {
        $.ajax({
            // This page will observe your ajax and decide what to do based
            // on the actions you send
            'url': '/dispatcher.php',
            'type': 'post',
            'data': data,
            'success': function(response) {
                // Run your function here
                func(response);
            }
        });

        return self;
    };
}

// Document ready    
$(function(){
    // Create ajax instance
    var Remote = new MyAjaxEngine($);
    // Run the ajax right from the start
    // send login_form action 
    Remote.ajax({"action":"login_form"},function(response){
        // Write hrml to the container
        $("#container").html(response);
    });
    // Listen for the form submission
    $(this).on('submit','#loginForm',function(e){
        // Stop submission
        e.preventDefault();
        // Create ajax call
        Remote.ajax({
            // This time send a login action
            "action":"login",
            // Send the form data in an array
            "form":$(this).serializeArray()
        },function(response){
            #write array back
            $("#container").html(response);
        });
    });
});
```

Now the dispatcher page will direct the ajax request. The dispatcher will write the response and the function in the success of the ajax call will place the contents of the write back into the container.

**/dispatcher.php**

```
<?php
# Just start session always
session_start();
# Don't even go on if there are no actions to compute
if(empty($_POST['action']))
    die('Request was empty.');
# Get database
include_once(__DIR__.'/connection/connection.php');
# Decide on actions
switch($_POST['action']) {
    case('login_form'):
        # Write back just the login form
        include(__DIR__.'/login.php');
        exit;
    case('login'):
        $form = $_POST['form'];
        $userName = $form["userNameBox"];
        $password = $form["passBox"];
        $connection = Connection::getConnection();
        $result = $connection->prepare("select * from english_students_table where user=:userNameMarker");
        $success = $result->execute(array(":userNameMarker" => $userName));
        $register = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($success && password_verify($password, $register["password"])){
            $_SESSION["userSession"] = $form["userNameBox"];
            die("<script> successfulLogin(); </script>");
        }else{
            die("<script> failedLogin(); </script>");
        }
}
```

I haven't tested this, but you should get the basic idea of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your login/login.php will generate either
`<form action="<script> successfulLogin(); </script>" ...>`
or `<form action="<script> failedLogin(); </script>" ...>`. The "action" attribute in form tag is suppose to be a remote page not a js function, right?

You can either rebuild nav bar and everything again in php function validateLogin(), or call php function validateLogin() through another ajax method in your javascript and update the exiting page with the result accordingly.

Comment: I think you pretty much said exactly what I already wrote in my answer. How is your answer an improvement to what was already stated/demonstrated?

Comment: if i understand corretly, you want the nav bar and everything else to be displayed after validateLogin is called, right?